# Adding new variable to dataframe

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I am trying to add a randomly generated variable to an already existing dataframe. I get an error message, but can't figure out why.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['age'])


 # Add income:
income_5 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=(nrows(df,))+1                          
df['income5'] = income_5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing `size=(nrows(df,)` to `size=(len(df),)` it works, so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['age'])


 # Add income:
income_5 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=(len(df),))+1                          
df['income5'] = income_5
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be `size=df.shape[0]` or `size=len(df)`:

```
income_5 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=df.shape[0])
df['income5'] = income_5
```

Example:

```
   age  income5
0   10        0
1   20        3
2   30        0
3   40        3
4   50        0
5   60        3
6   70        0
7   80        0
8   90        2
9  100        1
```

NB. You don't need the intermediate variable:

```
df['income5'] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=df.shape[0])
```